# move parent form when child form moves in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

ok , i searched but didnt find what i want so far...

i have a main form and another form named `RadEditTemplate`.. i `ShowDialog()` the edit form like this :

```
 new RadEditTemplate().ShowDialog();
```

i made the `RadEditTemplate` form the same size as the main form and made it center.

i want to lock these forms together so when i move the editform the main form move with it as well.
i have seen this in `Winscp` app before.
how can i do this ?

Comment: If your goal is to don't allow the user to the not view the form, can't you just hide it?

Comment: @MatteoUmili i did it already but i didnt like the motion,and there was a problem with centertoparent(),it doesent find the parent so it centers to the screen which i dont want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MainForm:

```
Form RadEditTemplate = new Form();
RadEditTemplate.Move+=On_Move;
RadEditTemplate.ShowDialog();

void On_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Location = new Point(((Form)sender).Location.X, ((Form)sender).Location.Y);
}
```

Comment: it did the job,thanks . but everytime i open the editform  it jumps to a random location,why is that so?

Comment: You must set RadEditTemplate default Location or StartPosition.

Comment: i dd that already but no luck ...     RadEditTemplate.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

Comment: i fixed that issue by defining an int step=0; variable to prevent On_Move method from executing for the first time.if its needed ill post the code here ..but thank you for your good answer.